# Android PVMFErrResourceConfiguration in Video play

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I used the following code for playing a progressive steaming video.

```
path = "http://www.languagehostess.com/videos/aka1.mp4";
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(path);
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,myUri);
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
```

Initially it is giving `PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback` error. To solve it, I use `MP4Box with "hint for rtp/rtsp"` and mux it to solve `moov/mdat` problem. When I upload the new muxed file and try to play it, it is giving  `PVMFErrResourceConfiguration` error. What is the problem in my code or video?

Addition: This problem is arising in Android 2.1, But in Android 2.2, it is working fine. Does Android 2.1 not support progressive MP4 video steaming?